# Creating interconnected 'Features' through 'Relationships' in Java

Tags: java, relationship, procedural-generation

For my project, I am trying to create a program that can generate a world that is filled with **'Features'** of different types (e.g. People, Settlements, Organisations, etc.) which I have made as subclasses to **'Feature'**. These **'Features'** are linked together through **'Relationships'** (Made up of a *subject* **'Feature'**, the *predicate*, and an *object* **'Feature'** e.g. *Person A 'is married to' Person B*) where the each Feature should store a reference to the other as well as what type of **'Relationship'** links them.

The program will work through iteration; First by generating some **'Features'** with random attributes. Then taking some of those **'Features'** and giving them a compatible **'Relationship'** based on its type and attributes. Then either completing the **'Relationship'** with a compatible pre-existing **'Feature'** or by generating a new one that is compatible. Then finally making any attribute changes based on the applied 'Relationships' (For example if a relationship is formed *Person A is the child of Person B*, their last name changes to match). This will go on until certain criteria are met.

A **'Relationship'** can vary.

> It can be ***Unidirectional*** or ***Bidirectional***; If *Person A is a sibling of Person B* then *Person B is a sibling of Person A* so it is ***Bidirectional***. Whereas if *Person A is the mother of Person B* then it is not the same going back, instead it would be *Person B is the child of Person A*, so it is ***Unidirectional***.

> A **'Feature'** can either have a ***Single*** or ***Multiple*** of a type of **'Relationship'**; Person A can have multiple siblings, but cannot have multiple (biological) mothers.

> A **'Relationship'** has constraints as to the types of **'Features'** can be the subject and object; The **'Relationship'** of *a Person is the ruler of a Settlement/a Settlement is ruled by a Person*. Now an obvious constraint here is the correct **'Feature'** subtype (Person/Settlement) must be used, but also the Settlement can't already have a ruler, as well as the Person must be of a certain age. So attribute and class type checks/filters would need to be implemented.

I am having an issue with how to represent this abstract concept of a **'Relationship'**, and currently have tried having each **'Feature'** hold a HashMap with the keys as the **'Relationship'** and the **'Feature'** as the value, though this would be actually be two separate links rather than one unifying **'Relationship'**. For example, if *Person A is the ruler of Settlement B*, then Person A would have a HashMap key/value stored of *"ruler of" : Settlement B*, and Settlement B would have one stored separately of *"ruled by" : Person A*. Now if later on in the generation, *Person C 'killed' Person A*, then Person A would no longer be the ruler and its **'Relationship'** key/value would be removed, but there is no explicit link to the other **'Relationship'** key/value stored in Settlement B, which could potentially result in mismatched **Relationships**.

I have also tried to implement my own **'Relationship'** object type (As well as a **'Predicate'** object type, which holds a **Feature** subject, **Feature** object, **Predicate** predicate) but I just can't figure out how to get it to work how I am envisioning the abstract concept in my head.

If you have an idea as to how I could achieve something like this, please let me know and if you need any further clarification please ask.

Comment: These relationships sound like the relations in a relational database. Looking at how relational databases are represented may be helpful to you. I think they are often represented by B-trees, for example java.util.Treemap